# Access Shapes in a group individually BY NAME in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, grouping, shapes

I manually grouped some items in excel so I can set some things up easier.
Also I thought some things would be easier in VBA, but also I need to traverse all those shapes in the group using their name, since after grouping using indexes won't serve as they are not in the desired order.

I used the following things:

```
'Does not work
Sheet1.Shapes("Group1").GroupItems("Shape1").Top

'Works but not the wanted solution as they are unsorted.
Sheet1.Shapes("Group1").GroupItems(1).Top
```

Is there a way to access shapes that are in a group individually **BY NAME**?

Comment: I'm guessing you'll have to loop through the items and test their name.

Comment: What type of error are you getting? I just tested it, and I was able to refer to the group item by name.  Check to make sure that the name is spelled correctly.  In any case, since you have the name of the group item, which essentially is a shape, you can refer to it directly by using the Shapes object (`ie Sheet1.Shapes(Shape1").Top`).

Comment: @Domenic Not that.
I meant to refer to an individual shape that is part of a group.

Comment: Yes, I was able to refer to an individual shape within a group.  What type of error are you getting?

Comment: @Domenic Something like Could find the specified element.

Comment: It looks like you don't have a group named "Group1" or a shape named "Shape1".  If this is not the case, check for spelling errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this, not sure you can directly access the name.

```
Sub x()

Dim s1 As Shape
Dim s2 As Shape

For Each s1 In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If s1.Type = msoGroup Then
        For Each s2 In s1.GroupItems
            If s2.Name = "Shape1" Then MsgBox s2.Top
        Next s2
    End If
Next s1

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks SJR